# Vapor Swift Fluent very very slow query

Tags: swift, api, backend, vapor

i noticed a very bad performance of Fluent when i run a query written in Swift in Vapor. When i run a raw query in this way:

```
 SELECT *  FROM "Model"
```

the time of response is about 20-30 ms. If i run the query in this way:

```
Model.query(on: request).all()
```

the time of response is increased tenfold. Why? What's the problem?

Comment: Could you show the full code of how you're executing raw query?

Comment: is this: ```return request.withPooledConnection(to: .psql) { (conn: PostgreSQLDatabase.Connection) -> EventLoopFuture<[Model]> in
                return conn.raw("""
                    SELECT * FROM  "Model"
                    .all(decoding: Model.self)
            }```

Comment: Are you running with `-c release` or build configuration: release in Xcode?

Comment: no. Should be faster with release configuration?

Comment: @nunziogiuliocaggegi You ought to at least try it. Performance can very dramatically between release and debug builds. If it's still slow on a release build we can try and see what we can do to improve the time.

Comment: @nunziogiuliocaggegi you could try my SwifQL lib btw

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so much? It seems valid based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A big chunk of the extra time there is likely to be decoding of the query result into Model objects.

Also work is being done on Vapor 4 (and the new Fluent version to go with it) which will make database queries a lot faster.

Comment: By using cursors or something like that?